# Can't give href to a link, error: "Reverse for 'foo' not found"

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, url-routing

I'm new to the django and the error that i got is: **"Reverse for 'influencers' not found. 'influencers' is not a valid view function or pattern name"**. What i want to do is redirect two different urls (site.com && site.com/influencers) to the same view. This is because i have a side menu which contains a tab called "Influencers" and i want both this link and "mysite.com" to work. I even accepted not using mysite.com/influencers and tryed something like href="{% url '' %}" but it didn't work either.

This line is in my **base.html** file which causes the error:

```
<a href="{% url 'app1:influencers' %}" class="side_link">  >&nbsp Influencers</a>
```

Here is my view:

```
class InfluencerList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Influencer
```

That's my **urls.py** file:

```
app_name = 'app1'
urlpatterns = [

    path('', InfluencerList.as_view()),
    path('influencers', InfluencerList.as_view()),
]
```

I appreciate any help or advices.

Comment: You need to specify the name of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the *name* of the path:

```
app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', InfluencerList.as_view()),
    path('influencers', InfluencerList.as_view(), name='influencers'),
]
```

I find it a bit "*odd*" that you use exactly the same view on two different paths. It is probably better to only list the same view (with the same parameters, etc.) once.

**EDIT**: You can make use of a [**`RedirectView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) to let the first path redirect to the second like:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='app1:influencers')),
    path('influencers', InfluencerList.as_view(), name='influencers'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, can u clarify how and where django uses the name parameter? I want to redirect user to the same view either he uses the just website url (mysite.com) or clicks the "Influencers" tab from the menu. Maybe there should be a command which redirects user to "mysite.com/influencers" when he enters just "mysite.com". I didn't get your last sentence and did a google search as "django listing same views" but it also didn't help me.

Comment: @İbrahimAkar: you can make use of a `RedirectView` to do the proper redirection. As for the name, this is an identifier to refer to the view. So the first parameter (`''` or `'influencers'` here), is *not* used to identify a view. If you thus want to point to a certain path, you will need to give it a name. Not per se the same as the path itself.

Comment: I tryed using RedirectView as u referred but i got the same error that i mentioned in my first post. "mysite.com" doesn't work but "mysite.com/influencers" is working

Comment: @İbrahimAkar: sorry, that should have been `app1:influencers`.